# Using jQuery $.each with Json erroring with 1 result

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, jsonp

Basically I am transforming a JSON result into html and using $.each it iterate through multiple keys. For example, I am pulling back facebook posts and iterating through the likes in that post.

The problem lies in the fact that when there are multiple "likes" everything works great! although when there is only 1 "like" the "source" key is removed from the result set and my javascript breaks because I expect it to be there. Any idea why the $.each is skipping a level for single nodes? The following is my code:

*** JQUERY ****

```
          $.each(post.likes.item, function(i, like){
             $(currentpost).find('div.cc_likes').append(like + ',');
             console.log(like)
          });
```

*** JSON RESULT ****

*** Single Like

```
       likes": {
            "item": {
                "source": {
                    "cta": "Mary Smith",
                    "url": "http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/",
                    "photo": {
                        "image": "https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/"
                    }
                }
            },
```

Result in console:

```
    Object 
      cta: "MaryAnn Smith" 
      photo: Object 
      url: "http://www.facebook.com/"
```

*** Multiple Likes

```
        "likes": {
            "item": [
                {
                    "source": {
                        "cta": "Bobby Carnes Sr.",
                        "url": "http:\/\/www.facebook.com",
                        "photo": {
                            "image": "https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "cta": "Jenna Purdy",
                        "url": "http:\/\/www.facebook.com\",
                        "photo": {
                            "image": "https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "cta": "Kevin Say",
                        "url": "http:\/\/www.facebook.com\",
                        "photo": {
                            "image": "https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "count": "10",
            "count_display": "10"
        },
```

Result in console:

```
    Object
      source: Object
        cta: "Kevin Smith"
        photo: Object
        url: "http://www.facebook.com/"
```

Comment: You should change your JSON to always use an array.  This makes everything much simpler.

Comment: you should handle the case of single like separately

Comment: Unless you're stuck with it being an object when it's single, in which case you will need to test to see if it has a length property before passing it to $.each

Comment: Great thanks, It all depends on that the DEV team wants to do. I'll see if we can't make it an array. Thanks so much for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$.each()` needs an array or array like object as argument, before using the object `post.likes.item` check if it is an array of not.
Following code will always pass an array to jQuery -

```
     $.each([].concat(post.likes.item), function(i, like){
         $(currentpost).find('div.cc_likes').append(like + ',');
         console.log(like)
      });
```

**Explanation**

`[]` is an empty array in JavaScript. Every array in JavaScript has a `concat` method.

`[].concat(obj)` concats `obj` to the empty array and returns an array.

- if `obj` is not an array, result is `[obj]` which is an array with one item.
- if `obj` is an array, then result is a deep copy of `obj` which is already an array.

[More about concat method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: So what exactly does the [] do? This worked great! I'm just trying to figure out why. And what i the context of "concat" here.

Answer (score 1):

```
        if ( isArray ) {
        for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
                value = callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] );

                if ( value === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for ( i in obj ) {
                value = callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] );

                if ( value === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

That is the jquery code being run on your JSON return. What's happening is, when you are looking at multiple results, it is looping through the array, return each base level object. However, when you are running it on a single return, it is looping through the object properties(in this case, "source"), and returning the value of that property.

You have two choices here. You can either make sure single items are still put in an array, or you can do a check for single items on the client side. The way Moazzam Khan suggests is the best way to do it in most cases.